# User Stories structure [e.g in BDD]

Tags: php, symfony, bdd, behat, user-stories

I am currently thinking a lot about how to structure best user stories, in my case its when I'm using the BDD approach - write User stories at the beginning of the dev.

Let's assume we have the following "new features": a registration and account settings. In the system are anonymous, authenticated (normal users that are logged in their account) and admin users (advanced users) as roles.

An anonymous user is as the only one allowed to register but not allowed to use the settings feature, an authenticated user can update its settings and an admin can update his settings and additional stuff but both can't register (again).

What is the best way to structure a feature - that may be used by different roles but not all in a different way - or a feature that may only be used by one role in bdd user stories?

Comment: Your question seems to be interesting, but needs to be more precise, maybe create an example of implementation in order to ask for a real salvageable issue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for, is a Scenario Outline.

You seem to be trying to achieve something like this:

```
@javascript
Feature: When I am not logged in, I should not be able to access certain pages within the site

Rules:
- Logged in users should be able to see pages that users not logged in should not.
- Logged in users should not be able to follow a link to the registrations screen

Scenario Outline: Following links to the registrations screen.
Given I go to "<urlwithlink>"
And I click on "<link>"
And wait "(Insert time to wait for page to load here)"
Then the url should match "(Insert registrationsPage)"

Examples:
|urlwithlink|link|
(Put some examples here)

Scenario Outline: When I am logged in, I should not be able to follow those links
Given I am logged in as a user
And I go to "<urlwithlink>"
Then I should not see "<link>"

Examples:
|urlwithlink|link|
(Insert same examples as above)

Scenario: When I am not logged in, I should not be able to access the settings screen
Given I go to "(Insert where link to settings is, here)"
And the "(link to settings)" should be disabled (or use I should not see an "(link to settings)" element)

Scenario: When I am logged in, I should be able to access the settings screen
Given I am logged in as a user
And I go to "(Insert where link to settings is here)"
Then the "(link to settings)" should not be disabled (or use I should see an "(link to settings)" element)
```

If you would like the extra steps for your context:

```
 /**
 * @Then /^(?:|I )click (?:on |)(?:|the )"([^"]*)"(?:|.*)$/
 */
public
function iClickOn($arg1)
{
    $findName = $this->getSession()->getPage()->find("css", $arg1);
    if (!$findName) {
        throw new Exception($arg1 . " could not be found");
    } else {
        $findName->click();
    }
}

/**
 * Simply wait the period of time.
 *
 * @Given /^(?:I |)(?:wait|pause for|take a break for) "([^"]*)"(?:|.*)/
 * @param int $milliseconds
 *
 */
public
function wait($milliseconds)
{
    $this->getSession()->wait($milliseconds);
}

/**
 * @Then /^(?:|the |an? )"([^"]*)" (?:|element )(?:is|should)(?P<negate>(?:n\'t| not)?) (?:|be )disabled$/
 *
 * @param string $elementCSS
 * @param string $negate
 *
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function theElementShouldBeDisabled($elementCSS, $negate)
{
    {
        $page = $this->getSession()->getPage();
        $element = $page->find("css", $elementCSS);
        if (!$element) {
            throw new Exception($elementCSS . ' does not exist');
        }
        $attributeValue = $element->getAttribute("disabled");

        if (is_numeric(strpos($negate, ' not')) || is_numeric(strpos($negate, 'n\'t'))) {
            if ($attributeValue) {
                if (is_numeric(strpos($attributeValue, "disabled"))) {
                    throw new Exception('The element ' . $elementCSS . ' is disabled');
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (!$attributeValue) {
                throw new Exception($elementCSS . ' does not have a disabled attribute');
            } else if (!is_numeric(strpos($attributeValue, "disabled"))) {
                throw new Exception('The element ' . $elementCSS . ' is not disabled');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That should do that, and I hope this helps.

You may want to split the settings and the links into two different files, if you want to structure it differently

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yeah i wanted to collect some.ways people handle the described situation, and outline scenarios might handle it, appreciate your sharing :)

Comment: Scenario Outlines are the best way to follow the same steps, without having to follow the same link every time.

Behat reads "Scenario Outline:" finds the Examples heading row, and takes everything within these: <>, and replaces it with whatever is in the column containing the letters inside them.

I've used Scenario Outlines for breadcrumbs, links and being able to search for a variety of things within search boxes, without cluttering up the .feature file.

Comment: Yes I know what scenario outlines are, and thats why I said they "might" be a way to handle sometimes the "role problem", I did not say that it is a clean very good solution but all thoughts are welcome here. I've been searching a lot in the internet and couldn't find a site where different approaches, or at least any approach is shown, thats why I created this thread.

Answer (score 1):

1) The "As a [role]" is not about an access role but who requires the feature. Mostly, it's some stakeholder who requires features so that the company can benefit and do better business.

2) Different access should be described by more scenarios in the same feature file. However, all your access roles are not crucial to explain the feature. Despite the fact that tools behind the Gherkin can test, Gherkin features and scenarios are more about capturing the idea behind them than cover all possible scenarios. Choose 1 positive scenario for covering each functionality and the rest lay down to lower testing levels, mostly unit tests.

Try to keep in mind the test pyramid where acceptance tests have only a small part of all testing.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I totally agree with your second point, Im using Behat for Acceptance, PHPUnit for integration and phpspec for unit tests, but what I don't understand is your nr. 1). A user story might have the part "As an authenticated user", or "As an anonymous user" etc. Is this what you meant by stakeholders? If so, I also agree on that point, if not, please let me know a bit more detail about your nr 1 :).Your last sentence is right too, but you should also keep in mind that even if it is a small part, it is one of the most important

Comment: Oh yes, now I see - An anonymous user is not a role, thats what you meant. yeh youre right!

Comment: Ad 1) Let's assume that it's a one-man e-shop project, then the story could be like "As a shop owner I want to have a user registration so that users don't need to fill their credentials again and would likely come to buy again".  That said the story is about describing the benefit of the feature. If you would have something like "As a user I want to register so I can be registered" doesn't say any value.

Comment: Ad 2) Behat is about describing features of your application. A simple scenario with the registration is descriptive enough. Of course, covering all edge cases is important, but it's not the purpose of Behat, this is why there are lower level tests like unit tests.

Comment: Ok, but I think you're wrong with number 1 as symfony core developers also use stuff like anonym, aurhenticated etc

Comment: Symfony is a framework, not a business project. The story in the feature file is for understanding WHY there is that feature. The author of BDD can tell you more in his post [http://dannorth.net/whats-in-a-story/](http://dannorth.net/whats-in-a-story/).

Comment: I don't want to say that it must be only 1 scenario. Moreless it's up to you to decide what is crucial to describe explicitly by a scenario. For me, it's implicitly clear that already authenticated user can't register again. BUT writing features and scenarios shouldn't be only up to the developer. A stakeholder and Q&A should be involved then it comes from a conversation what should be explicitly described, and what is more implicit behaviour so that it can be specified on a lower level.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts and the interesting link!